# Button inside ListView not respond to ItemClick

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have three buttons inside ListView.
I tried to click each of the button, however the ItemClick function was not triggered.

There is the `xaml` file of the ListView

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="DefaultWideSideItemTemplate" x:DataType="ui:AppMenuItem">
            <Grid>
                <ui:ButtonWithIcon IconContent="{x:Bind Icon}"
                                       Content="{x:Bind Name}"
                                       Style="{StaticResource TransparentFontButtonStyle}"
                />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <others:SideMenuItemTemplateSelector DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultWideSideItemTemplate}" x:Key="WideSideItemTemplateSelector"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

<ListView Style="{StaticResource HorizontalCenterListView}" 
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind MenuItemCollection}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  x:Name="SideMenuListView"
                  Loaded="SideMenuListView_Loaded"
                  ItemClick="SideMenuListView_ItemClick"
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource WideSideItemTemplateSelector}">
            </ListView>
```

There is the code where ItemClick was defined.

```
        public event EventHandler<AppMenuItem> SideMenuItemClick;

        private void SideMenuListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
          // DO SOMETHING HERE
        }
```

There is the `xaml` file of the `ui:ButtonWithIcon`

```
 <Style x:Key="TransparentFontButtonStyle" TargetType="ui:ButtonWithIcon">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,32,0,7"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ui:ButtonWithIcon">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="IconContent"
                            Text="{Binding IconContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                            FontSize="30"/>
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="Text"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            FontSize="14"
                            Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

What did I understand wrong about ListView? Buttons can not be used in ListView?

Update: ButtonWithIcon

```
    public class ButtonWithIcon : Button
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IconContentProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("IconContent", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonWithIcon), new PropertyMetadata(default));

        public string IconContent
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(IconContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IconContentProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

Update 2:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="DefaultWideSideItemTemplate" x:DataType="ui:AppMenuItem">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,32,0,7">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Icon}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                           FontSize="30"/>
                    <TextBlock 
                           Text="{x:Bind Name}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="0,10,0,0"
                           FontSize="14"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ui:ButtonWithIcon` is a custom button control, then this is expected behavior. When you click on the custom button, the click event is captured by the button, so the `ListView` won't trigger the `ItemClick` event. A simple way to confirm is that you could click on the place that does not belong to the custom button. It should fire the `ItemClick` event of the ListView.

**Update:**
Since your code is too messy, I made a simple test using some of your code:

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind MenuItemCollection}"
              
              x:Name="SideMenuListView"
              Loaded="SideMenuListView_Loaded"
              ItemClick="SideMenuListView_ItemClick"
              >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,32,0,7">
                       
                        <TextBlock 
                       Text="{Binding}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="0,10,0,0"
                       FontSize="14"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

This works correctly.

You could remove the extra parts of your code to narrow down the issue. Start with a easy sample like the above.

Comment: Please see the update. The ``ButtonWithIcon`` is a custom button. Is there a way to let ``ListView`` trigger the ItemClick event?

Comment: So the custom button is a button control. If you insist on using a button control, the only way is to disable the button. Set `button.IsEnabled=False`.

Comment: Is there another way to achieve a button-like with two textblocks just like the ``ButtonWithIcon`` I mentioned before? Thanks

Comment: There are different ways to create a control that looks like a button. You could choose controls that you like. For me, I would use a border and some textblocks

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I change it to Update 2, how ever when ever click each of the textblock, the ItemClick is still not triggered?

Comment: I've made a simple test and you could check my update

Comment: Thank you very much, I found the question and now it works correctly!